# Two Level Implementation of NOR gate?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I have a function F(w,x,y,z) = wx'+w'z'+y'z'

Using P.O.S., the function becomes: F=(w'+z)(x+z)(w+x+y)

If I was asked to implement the function with a two-level **NOR** gate circuit, I assume this means I may only have **NOR** gates. However, one of the terms have a **NOT**, and makes it three-level?
Here's my implementation with "*only*" NOR gates: 
[image: implementation]

Is my implementation two-level or three-level. How can I make it two-level if it isn't?

Comment: It's two-level if w' is given to you?

Comment: Espresso says that W X'  + W' Z'  + Y' Z' = (W+Z')(X'+Z')(W'+X'+Y') so I'm wondering about your equivalence, to start.

Comment: Try: ((W' + X' + Y')' + (X' + Z')' + (W + Z')')'

Comment: I agree with @jonk.  Your 2nd expression is wrong.  You will have 4 inverters, 2 2-input NORs and 2 3-input NORs.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Yes. That's exactly what I came up with and why I wrote out that final expression to show those details.

Comment: @jonk I went through WolframAlpha.  Same answer as yours.  Since OP has it in a simulator, you'd think verification would be easy.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I didn't know there was a feature on Alpha that could do that. Hehe. I just wrote it out by hand. Now I probably need to go learn about Alpha (which I never use.)

Comment: @jonk  It's awkward until you get used to the syntax.   What I am surprised at, is Google not being able to do it.